# Overloads for '...' exist with these result types: ClosedRange<Bound>, CountableClosedRange<Bound>

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

**Swift 2**

```
let gap = CGFloat(randomInRange(StackGapMinWidth...maxGap))
```

> Missing argument label 'range:' in call

**Swift 3** - new error

```
let gap = CGFloat(randomInRange(range: StackGapMinWidth...maxGap))
```

> No '...' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Range'
>
> Overloads for '...' exist with these result types: ClosedRange, CountableClosedRange

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Swift 3, `..<` and `...` produce different kinds of ranges:

- `..<` produces a `Range` (or `CountableRange`, depending on the underlying type) which describes a half-open range that does not include the upper bound.
- `...` produces a `ClosedRange` (or `CountableClosedRange`) which describes a closed range that includes the upper bound.

If the `randomInRange()` calculates a random number in the given range,
*including* the upper bound, then it should be defined as

```
func randomInRange(range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
    // ...
}
```

and you can call it as

```
let lo = 1
let hi = 10
let r = randomInRange(range: lo ... hi)
```