# Swift 2 to 3 Migration for NSRange

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, ios10, swift-extensions

I'm trying to use a random number extension I created that worked in swift 2 and fails in Swift 3.  Not sure why.

Here is the code.

```
let aRandomInt = Int.random(range:0...2)

//Extention to INT to create random number in range.
extension Int
{
    static func random(range: Range<Int> ) -> Int
    {
        var offset = 0

        if range.lowerBound < 0   // allow negative ranges
        {
            offset = abs(range.lowerBound)
        }

        let mini = UInt32(range.lowerBound + offset)
        let maxi = UInt32(range.upperBound   + offset)

        return Int(mini + arc4random_uniform(maxi - mini)) - offset
    }
}
```

The error I get is...

**No '...' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Range'**

This error occurs on the line that says let aRandomInt = Int.random(range:0...2)

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915972/overloads-for-exist-with-these-result-types-closedrangebound-countable ?

Comment: quite possibly looks like they changed ranges a lot, let me read that article.

Comment: As in the referenced thread, you just have to replace `Range<Int>` by `ClosedRange<Int>` in the function definition.

Comment: Looks like it does, yeah if you change to this.. let lo = 0;
        let hi = 2;
        let aRandomInt = Int.random(range:lo...hi), then like you said change it to ClosedRange<Int> you can put that as answer it worked!